# FullCalendar v4 using Recurring Event, causing event with less than 24H not showing

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I was using fullcalendar v4 for mycalendar with something like :

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    $data[] = [
        'id'              => $row->calendar_id,
        'title'           => $row->calendar_title,
        'startRecur'      => $row->calendar_startdate,
        'endRecur'        => $row->calendar_enddate,
        'startTime'       => $row->calendar_starttime,
        'endTime'         => $row->calendar_endtime,
        'daysOfWeek'      => $row->calendar_dow,
        'backgroundColor' => '#6453e9',
        'textColor'       => '#ffffff'
    ];
}
```

For Example something like below, will not shown up

```
id :3
title : "Not recurring"
startRecur : "2022-01-26"
endRecur : "2022-01-26"
startTime : "09:00:00"
endTime : "12:00:00"
daysOfWeek : ""
backgroundColor : "#6453e9"
textColor : "#ffffff"
```

And something like below will only showing as one day event

```
id :4
title : "Recurring event"
startRecur : "2022-01-26"
endRecur : "2022-01-27"
startTime : "09:00:00"
endTime : "12:00:00"
daysOfWeek : ""
backgroundColor : "#6453e9"
textColor : "#ffffff"
```

And for another event that have daysOfWeek, it has the same issue, the last day of the event won't showing up
What's wrong with it?

Comment: `And something like below will only showing as one day event`...because end dates are **exclusive** (as per the fullcalendar documentation). It's the same reason for all the cases you've mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solution, you just have to add `HH:MM` to your `recurStart` and `recurEnd`